# Permission denied when running logrotate with anacron

Tags: permissions, cron, selinux, logrotate

I am trying to figure out what is causing `anacron` to send me the following error message:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:

/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log-20140710.gz: Permission denied
error: error running last action script for /var/log/mariadb/*.log
```

These are the relevant configs:

```
# /etc/cron.d
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
------------------------------------------
# /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron
...
/usr/sbin/anacron -s
------------------------------------------
# /etc/anacrontab
...
1   5   cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
------------------------------------------
# /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
...
------------------------------------------
# /etc/logrotate.conf
...
include /etc/logrotate.d
...
```

This is the main config in question:

```
# /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb

/var/log/mariadb/*.log {
  create 640 mysql mysql
  missingok
  sharedscripts
  nodelaycompress

  postrotate
   .....

  lastaction

    dir="/var/log/mariadb/"
    today=$(date -u +%Y%m%d)
    attach1=$(ls -t1 ${dir}mariadb*gz 2>&1 head -1 | grep $today)
    ....

    attachment=""
    totalsize=0
    if [[ $attach1 ]]; then
     attachment+=" -a $attach1"
     totalsize=$((totalsize + $(stat -c %s $attach1)))
    fi
    ....
  endscript
}
```

When I tested the above on commandline with `# logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf`, there is no error. But when anacron is running it, it gets permission denied error as shown above. I am guessing that the error is generated when it runs the `stat` command.

I have the following permission setting for the file in question

```
-rw-r-----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 mariadb.log-20140711.gz
```

The SELinux context looks fine to me and I don't see any avc error in my journal log, so it shouldn't be due to SELinux. Also, from `cron.d`, `run-parts` is executed with root as user, so there shouldn't be a permission problem.

I have read this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120793) of which the recommendation is to do `strace`. But I don't have `strace` and I am not allowed to install it. Is there anyone who can tell me what is causing the permission error?

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this with clamd.  Make sure that the user running logrotate has permission to write to /var/log/mariadb.

Try 
   su root root
at the top of the configuration directive.